# InDesign can't load sample plug-in

Tags: c++, adobe, adobe-indesign

Hy
It's my first expirience with Adobe SDK, I'm using InDesign SDK to create my custom plug-in, but I can't even get the sample plug-ins to load into InDesign.
I opened up some projects located in \Adobe InDesign CS6 Plugin SDK\build\win\prj, a couple of them I compiled with visual studio 2013 in x64 build configuration. After building succesfully the project i grabbed the \Adobe InDesign CS6 Plugin SDK\build\win\releasex64\sdk and moved the sdk folder to \Plug-Ins, but when I try to open InDesign I receive an error message telling me that:" InDesign could note laod the plugin, please try and reinstall it". I did but nothing happened.
I then build some other projects with microsoft visual studio 2010 (as suggested by the getting started guide provided with the Adobe InDesign CS6 Plugin SDK), building them in release x86 configuration (x64 isn't possible with visual studio 2010) but I get the same exact problem...
I have InDesign x64 version installed.
Have you got some ideas on what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- At first, the version of InDesign SDK and Adobe InDesign should be matched. That's saying the plug-ins built with InDesign CS6 SDK can only be loaded by InDesign CS6. Since you mentioned `I have InDesign x64 version installed`, but InDesign CS6 only has 32bit on Windows.
- To load the plug-ins in CS6, build samples with Visual Studio 2010 using Release|Win32 build configuration.

Comment: Thank you, figured that out, I was using InDesign CC, instead of InDesign CS6, installed CS6, that fixed the problem! thank you!